# Non physically fearsible results from a 10 chemical reaction system (8 ODEs)

Tags: matlab, ode, negative-number

I'm trying to script a 10 chemical reaction system (image link below) with 8 components (so 8 ODEs) in order to get the reactor volume, but I'm getting negative values for most of the components. It may be something to do with the molar balances or the script itself so if anyone with some chemical background can look into it, I would apreciate it!

[image: Reaction system]

Data:

```
2,00e-06    48000   2,50e-13    -175000 0   0   0   0,76
23,20       182000  8,30e-14    -186000 2,30e-12    -124000 1   0,40
5,20e-07    68000   3,60e-14    -187000 0   0   0   0,85
0,00011     104000  4,00e-13    -168000 0   0   1   0,55
0,17        157000  4,50e-13    -166000 0   0   0   0,37
0,06        166000  1,60e-13    -211000 0   0   1   0,96
12000000    226000  0   0   0   0   0   0
9300        300000  0   0   0   0   0   0
0,00019     173000  0   0   0   0   1   1
0,026       220000  0   0   0   0   1   1
```

Function (OCML.m):

```
function dFdV = OCML( V , F0 , par , T , Pt)

%% Initial conditions

F = sum(F0);
y = F0./F;
pp = y * Pt;

p_CH4  = pp(1)   ;
p_O2   = pp(2)   ;
p_CO2  = pp(3)   ;
p_H2O  = pp(4)   ;
p_C2H6 = pp(5)   ;
p_CO   = pp(6)   ;
p_C2H4 = pp(7)   ;
p_H2   = pp(8)   ;

%% Parameters

ko = par(:,1)       ;
Ea = par(:,2)       ;
KCO2 = par(:,3)     ;
DHadCO2 = par(:,4)  ;
KO2 = par(:,5)      ;
DHadO2 = par(:,6)   ;
m = par(:,7)        ;
n = par(:,8)        ;
R = 8.314462        ;
ro_cat = 3600000    ; % g/m3

%% Stoichiometric coefficients matrix

N = [ -1   -2  1  2  0  0  0  0 ;
      -2 -0.5  0  1  1  0  0  0 ;
      -1   -1  0  1  0  1  0  1 ;
       0 -0.5  1  0  0  1  0  0 ;
       0 -0.5  0  1 -1  0  1  0 ;
       0   -2  0  2  0  2 -1  0 ;
       0    0  0  0 -1  0  1  1 ;
       0    0  0 -2  0  2 -1  4 ;
       0    0  1 -1  0 -1  0  1 ;
       0    0 -1  1  0  1  0 -1 ; ];

%% Reaction Rates

% Reaction 1

exp1 = exp(-Ea(1)/(R*T))                                ;
exp_ad1 = exp(-DHadCO2(1)/(R*T))                        ;
denom1 = 1 + KCO2(1) * exp_ad1 * p_CO2                  ;
r1 = ( ko(1) * exp1 * p_CH4^m(1) * p_O2^n(1) ) / denom1 ;

% Reaction 2

exp2 = exp(-Ea(2)/(R*T))                                                        ;
exp_ad2a = exp(-DHadO2(2)/(R*T))                                                ;
exp_ad2b = exp(-DHadCO2(2)/(R*T))                                               ;
denom2 = 1 + KO2(2) * exp_ad2a * p_O2 + KCO2(2) * exp_ad2b * p_CO2              ;
r2 = ( ko(2) * exp2 * ( KO2(2) * exp_ad2a * p_O2 )^n(2) * p_CH4 ) / denom2^2    ;

% Reaction 3

exp3 = exp(-Ea(3)/(R*T))                                ;
exp_ad3 = exp(-DHadCO2(3)/(R*T))                        ;
denom3 = 1 + KCO2(3) * exp_ad3 * p_CO2                  ;
r3 = ( ko(3) * exp3 * p_CH4^m(3) * p_O2^n(3) ) / denom3 ;

% Reaction 4

exp4 = exp(-Ea(4)/(R*T))                                ;
exp_ad4 = exp(-DHadCO2(4)/(R*T))                        ;
denom4 = 1 + KCO2(4) * exp_ad4 * p_CO2                  ;
r4 = ( ko(4) * exp4 * p_CO^m(4) * p_O2^n(4) ) / denom4  ;

% Reaction 5

exp5 = exp(-Ea(5)/(R*T))                                    ;
exp_ad5 = exp(-DHadCO2(5)/(R*T))                            ;
denom5 = 1 + KCO2(5) * exp_ad5 * p_CO2                      ;
r5 = ( ko(5) * exp5 * p_C2H6^m(5) * p_O2^n(5) ) / denom5    ;

% Reaction 6

exp6 = exp(-Ea(6)/(R*T))                                        ;
exp_ad6 = exp(-DHadCO2(6)/(R*T))                                ;
denom6 = 1 + KCO2(6) * exp_ad6 * p_CO2                          ;
r6 = ( ko(6) * exp6 * p_C2H4^m(6) * p_O2^n(6) ) / denom6    ;

% Reaction 7

exp7 = exp(-Ea(7)/(R*T))                ;
r7 = ko(7)* exp7 * p_C2H6  * ro_cat     ;

% Reaction 8

exp8 = exp(-Ea(8)/(R*T))                    ;
r8 = ko(8)* exp8 * p_C2H4^m(8) * p_H2O^n(8) ;

% Reaction 9

exp9 = exp(-Ea(9)/(R*T))                    ;
r9 = ko(9)* exp9 * p_CO^m(9) * p_H2O^n(9)   ;

% Reaction 10

exp10 = exp(-Ea(10)/(R*T))                     ;
r10 = ko(10)* exp10 * p_CO2^m(10) * p_H2^n(10) ;

r_vector = [ r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 r10 ]'  ;

%% Molar balances (dFx/dV)

dF_CH4dV  = sum(N(:,1).*r_vector)*ro_cat     ;
dF_O2dV   = sum(N(:,2).*r_vector)*ro_cat     ;
dF_CO2dV  = sum(N(:,3).*r_vector)*ro_cat     ;
dF_H2OdV  = sum(N(:,4).*r_vector)*ro_cat     ;
dF_C2H6dV = sum(N(:,5).*r_vector)*ro_cat     ;
dF_COdV   = sum(N(:,6).*r_vector)*ro_cat     ;
dF_C2H4dV = sum(N(:,7).*r_vector)*ro_cat     ;
dF_H2dV   = sum(N(:,8).*r_vector)*ro_cat     ;

dFdV = [ dF_CH4dV dF_O2dV dF_CO2dV dF_H2OdV dF_C2H6dV dF_COdV dF_C2H4dV dF_H2dV ]' ;
end
```

Script:

```
clear; clc; close all ; format long

%% Data

par=importdata('data.mat');

T = 273.15 + 850;
Pt = 101325;

% Methane and O2 feed
F0 = [ 27.77777778 9.259259259 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];

% Volume vector

V = 0.0:0.1:1 ;

% ODE solver

OCML_model = @(V,F0)[OCML(V,F0,par,T,Pt)]     ;
[ V, F_vector ] = ode15s(OCML_model,V,F0)      ;
```

Comment: This is still a bit too complicated to discuss here. Could you trim down the model a bit - I mean just give coefficients for all the thermodynamic calculations so we can focus on the  network. Maybe just including reactions 1, 3 & 10

Comment: Especially the lines `dF_C2H4dV = -(sum(N(:,3).*r_vector)/ro_cat + N(7,3)*r7*(ro_cat-1)/ro_cat );` confuse me. Can you explain this calculaiton in detail?

Comment: This reaction system has 2 types of reactions, one type that takes place on the catalyst and the other in the gas phase. Only the reaction 7 takes place in the gas phase, so only C2H4, C2H6 and H2 are involved in that reaction. As such, they must not be divided by the density of the catalyst, but since the other reaction terms must be divided by it, that assures that the reaction rate of 7 doesn't get divided by the catalyst density. Anyway, I found a much simpler way to do it and I've edited the code.

Comment: Can you write out reaction 1 with the actual numbers inserted?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the molar balance for the first component. Since it participates in the first 3 reactions: dF_CH4/dV = -( -r1 - 2*r2 - r3 ) / ro_cat

Comment: I found an error! The reactants must have a minus in the balance cause their derivative in function of the volume is negative while the products don't need it since the quantity is increasing with the volume! Changing this I don't get negative numbers, still, the amount of reactants isn't decreasing along the volume but it should.

Comment: I've managed to correct all the errors, it seems. Well, thanks for the little help I guess, and if anyone as other suggestions to improve the code, be my guest. :)

Comment: @DinisNunes: Implementing ODEs numerically is all about being very careful entering the equations and the parameter values. The more complex the system the harder this is. A tiny sign error or a transposition of digits can change everything. Once you think it's working you should continue going checking. [This blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/06/10/from) from The MathWorks details a method of implementing your ODE function from a set of symbolic equations, which may or may not help you. Also, what you have derived on paper can sometimes have errors in it too....

Comment: Thanks for the advice horchler! In this case, the error was in the balances, so I guess I'll have to be more careful deriving my expressions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have not mass-balance equations which involve fractions, like Michaëlis-Menten enzymatic kinetics, they usually serve as some quasi-steady state approximations, which might fail under low concentrations of the reagents. This could be one reason of negative values.

As a putty, you can use [`options = odeset('NonNegative',1);`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html#f1-754830). Which might give you still corrupted results.

But first check the equations, and start first with plain mass-action, and grow your system gradually. Then you'll see after which addition it fails. This is the main merit of [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) concept.